# Scatter years and month on X axis and days on Y axis

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a datetime series (called date) like this:

```
0     2012-06-26
1     2011-02-22
2     2012-06-06
3     2013-02-10
4     2004-01-01
5     2011-01-25
6     2015-11-02
```

And i want to scatter plot with dates for Y axis and months and years on X axis.

I've played around with pyplot.plot_date, but can't figure out any solution.

It shoud be something like [this](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/data/uploads/2012/03/outgoing-mail-diurnal-image.png) only with dates on Y axis.

Any advice?

Comment: Unfortunately, it remains unclear what you are trying to achieve. Since you have a single time series while scatter needs x and y input, it is not obvious which data should be where. Maybe you pick an example and tell how the first date of the time series should appear in the graph. Also the problem is not well defined: "Nothing works for me" is not a sufficient problem description. Please make sure you have read and understood [ask] and how to produce a [mcve]. Then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: I have this series of events happened on certain dates and i want to represent them as scatter plot with days on Y axis and months and years on X axis. SOmething like  [this](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/data/uploads/2012/03/outgoing-mail-diurnal-image.png) but with days on Y

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into matplotlib, it's really usefull.
This might also help you to start the plotting.

```
    dates = [
    '2012-06-26',
    '2011-02-22',
    '2012-06-06',
    '2013-02-10',
    '2004-01-01',
    '2011-01-25',
    '2015-11-02',
]

year = []
month = []
day = []


# Sorts your data in an useable dataset
def sort_data():
    for i in range(len(dates)):
        extracted_year = dates[i][0:4]
        extracted_year = int(extracted_year)
        year.append(extracted_year)
    for j in range(len(dates)):
        extracted_month = dates[j][5:7]
        extracted_month = int(extracted_month)
        month.append(extracted_month)
    for k in range(len(dates)):
        extracted_day = dates[k][8:10]
        extracted_day = int(extracted_day)
        day.append(extracted_day)

sort_data()

# Just checking if sort_date() worked correctly
print(year)
print(month)
print(day)
```

Comment: does matplotlib require data set to be sorted?

I can split months and years from it with 
dates.apply(lambda x: x.month) or dates.apply(lambda x: x.year)
since it is in datetime64 format.

But i can't figure aut how to plot dates on Y and month and year on X.

Answer (score 0):

As far my best solution is converting year and month to floats and days to int:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
dates = [
 '2012-06-26',
 '2011-02-22',
 '2012-06-06',
 '2013-02-10',
 '2004-01-01',
 '2011-01-25',
 '2015-11-02',]

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
ax.scatter(date.apply(lambda x: float(x.strftime('%Y.%m'))),date.apply(lambda x: x.day), marker='o')
```

Answer (score -1):

As your question is not completely clear to me, I assume you want to scatter plot all input datetime entries between oldest and recent most year (to be selected from the given input only).

Also, it is my very first attempt in "matplotlib" library. So, I just hope following answer would lead you to your expected result.

```
import datetime
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import MONDAY
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, MonthLocator, WeekdayLocator
from matplotlib.dates import date2num

# Input datetime series.
dt_series = ["2012-06-26", "2011-02-22", "2012-06-06", "2013-02-10", "2004-01-01", "2011-01-25", "2015-11-02"]

mondays = WeekdayLocator(MONDAY)
months = MonthLocator(range(1, 13), bymonthday=1, interval=6)
monthsFmt = DateFormatter("%b'%y")

# Loop to create our own X-axis and Y-axis values.
# mths is for X-axis values, which are months along with year.
# dates is for Y-axis values, which are dates.
mths = list()
dates = list()
for dt in dt_series:
    mths.append(date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(dt.replace('-', ''), "%Y%m%d")))
    dates.append(numpy.float64(float(dt.split('-')[2])))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(squeeze=True)
ax.plot_date(mths, dates, 'o', tz=None, xdate=True, ydate=False)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthsFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mondays)
ax.autoscale_view()
ax.grid(True)

fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

I would also suggest you to go through following link which I used for my reference:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo2.html

Thank You

Comment: Hi @MuzZzdY, have you tried this one ? This plots exactly what you have asked for.